# Output devices are recognized, but no sound plays on a cherry trail laptop

Tags: sound, alsa

[image: Screenshot with aplay -l and sound settings]

I have installed [Ubuntu 17.04 modified to work with intel Atom processors](http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/interim-ubuntu-1704-iso-with-mainline_29.html) and surprisingly most things work, but unfortunately not audio. Although there are recognized playback devices, no sound comes out of them. Pressing "Test Sound" for the first time creates the pop-up window, but pressing on either of the speakers yields no results. If I close the window and click "Test Sound" again, the window won't even pop up. Oddly enough, audio files won't play at all (eg. the progress bar is not moving) and playing YouTube videos make them buffer or fast forward - even if the video is muted. Same with videos on disk. **However** an external USB DAC works fine when plugged in and when it is plugged in all audio and video plays just right.

The device is Kiano Intelect X2

It physically has jack output, mini-HDMI output and stereo speakers.

Comment: There's no support for audio yet. Most experts hacking on this ended up using USB audio devices. Avoid "Bay Trail" and "Cherry Trail".

Comment: well just to give my 2c, I have an Asus X205TA (bay trail, Intel Atom) and used Ubuntu for a whole year with no audio (the card was never even detected), but with much determined collaboration a group of hackers and Realtek devs have written a patch and fingers crossed it will get merged some day. I don't think this question should be closed, because the support will come eventually. And @MichaelBay if you add some details and a reference for what you say, "that's because there's no audio support" can be the basis of a perfectly valid answer

Comment: @Zanna All I know comes from linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com